# Proxy relay for JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc, proxy, database-connection

I have a situation when I am only able to query a database from specific host. I am thinking to deploy some proxy relay component to that host, which I can connect to from my machine/local application like this is just a normal database, and that component will in turn relay all queries to real database.

local application -> [ proxy jdbc | jdbc connection ] -> {firewall rule, external network} -> database

Anybody aware of such libraries available?

Comment: Please contact me off-list via Dada Electronics Australia. I have a commercial product that does exactly this.

Comment: Why you couldn't just try proxy tunnel, like this: https://www.linuxschoolonline.com/tunnel-telnet-traffic-inside-ssh-using-port-forwarding/?

Comment: @oleg-sta, I'd probably would like to avoid sharing credentials on underlying database